# unable to extract value using Regular Expression in JMeter

Tags: regex, xpath, jmeter

I am unable to extract value using both Regular Expression and xPath in JMeter

```
<input id="capture_signin_transactionId_u13jjd6w9y1h167bhu5ut4fhbht0kwebuvqi6f0z" class="capture_transactionId_u13jjd6w9y1h167bhu5ut4fhbht0kwebuvqi6f0z" type="hidden" name="capture_transactionId" value="u13jjd6w9y1h167bhu5ut4fhbht0kwebuvqi6f0z" data-capturefield="undefined">
```

Regular Expression Extractor used:

```
Reference Name - capture_transactionId
name="capture_transactionId" value="(\w+{40}?)"
Template $1$
Match 1
Default Value - n/a
```

XPath extractor used:

```
Reference Name - capture_transactionId
xPath Query - //input[@type="hidden"][@name="capture_transactionId"]/@value
```

But I am unable to capture value.

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using XPath Extractor to parse HTML (not XML) response ensure that **Use Tidy (tolerant parser)** option is CHECKED (in [XPath Extractor's control panel](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)).

XPath query looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the Regular Expressions Extractor as follows:

```
Reference Name - capture_transactionId
name="capture_transactionId" value="(.*?)"
Template $1$
Match 1
Default Value - n/a
```